# Real time countdown timer that gets updated by user action. Connected to the database. Implementation?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, countdown

How would i implement such a timer?

Please take a moment to have a look at this countdown timer. http://bigdeal.com (see one of the products)

What would you do with the db. How would you intergrate with javascript?

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like you have made no effort to solve the problem and want someone to do all of it for you? Please post some code or an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Oh trust me. I've tried. No code i wrote would be relevant, it doesn't work. Which is why i'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to use an AJAX request to get all the new values.

Then you can repeat this AJAX request using `setInterval()`

```
var updateCountdowns = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_countdowns.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
             // update your countdowns
        }
    });
};

setInterval(updateCountdowns, 1000); // Repeated every 1000 ms (1 sec)
```

Comment: Please elaborate. I get the gist but i want to be sure.

Comment: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/ajax-update-content-every-x-seconds.html

Comment: You can Google: jquery ajax setInterval

Comment: have I answered your question?

Comment: Yes, i did some googling also but thanks very much for the example. I''ll give you the winning answer.